# Why does the power rule work?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, intuition, exponentiation

If $$f(x)=x^u$$ then the derivative function will always be $$f'(x)=u*x^{u-1}$$
I've been trying to figure out why that makes sense and I can't quite get there.

I know it can be proven with limits, but I'm looking for something more basic, something I can  picture in my head.

The derivative should be the slope of the function.
If $$f(x)=x^3=x^2*x$$ then the slope should be $x^2$. But it isn't. The power rule says it's $3x^2$.

I understand that it has to do with having variables where in a more simple equation there would be a constant. I'm trying to understand how that exactly translates into the power rule.

Comment: What if you write $x^3 = x*x*x$ and use the product rule. What do you get? What do you get with the product rule for $x^3 = x^2*x$? Do they all agree?

Comment: As per Amzoti's suggestion, if you want intuition think of the case where $u$ is an integer and use the product rule. So in the case of $x^3$, use the product rule and take the derivative of $x\cdot x\cdot x$. This is symmetric, so you will get $3\cdot x^2$.

Comment: Since the _definition_ of $f'(x)$ involves limits, you can't hope for "something more basic" that proves things about derivatives.

Comment: "If $f(x)=x^3=x^2\cdot x$ then the slope should be $x^2$" - Why? (You are perhaps confusing it with rules that work to find slopes of lines of the form $y=ax+b$; you simply take the $a$ in front of the $x$ then.)

Comment: @Amzoti, so that is just restating the question as.... why does the product rule work?

Comment: Essentially, yes, it is the product rule. However, with math you can usually cast problems into other domains, such as Andre's answer with the Binomial approach. Regards

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First let's try to understand why the derivative of the function $f$ given by $f(x) = x^2$ is equal to $2x$ and not to $x$.  (The product rule and the power rule are both generalizations of this.)

Imagine that you have a square whose sides have length $x$.  Now imagine what happens to its area if we increase the length of each side by a small amount $\Delta x$.  We can do this by adding three regions to the picture: two thin rectangles measuring $x$ by $\Delta x$ (say one on the right of the square and another on the top) and one small square measuring $\Delta x$ by $\Delta x$ (say added in the top right corner.)  So the change in the area $x^2$ is equal to $2x \cdot \Delta x + (\Delta x)^2$.  If we divide this by $\Delta x$ and take the limit as $\Delta x$ approaches zero, we get $2x$.

So geometrically what is happening is that the small square in the corner is too small to matter, but you have to count *both* rectangles.  If you only count one of them, you will get the answer $x$; however, this only tells you what happens when you lengthen, say, the horizontal sides and not the vertical sides of your square to get a rectangle. This is a different problem than the one under consideration, which asks (after we put it in geometrical terms) how the area varies as we lengthen *all* the sides.

Comment: That's a really cool way to explain it. Like the OP, I too used to understand the math of the limits, but couldn't picture it. My high school calculus teacher explained it the same way as @Trevor, and it really helped me get my head around the concept visually.

Comment: Hm, but this doesn't explain why power rule is valid in, say $y=\sqrt x$, or $x^\pi$.

Answer (score 11):

If you know the product rule, you can derive this for when $u$ is a positive integer, which should give you a basic intuitive understanding.

Suppose, as an example, that $f(x) = x^2$. 
Equivalently, $f(x) = x*x$. By using the product rule, we have
$$f(x) = (1)(x) + (x)(1) $$
$$= 2x$$

More generally, suppose that $f(x) = x^u$. Suppose for now that $u$ is a positive integer, which allows us to expand like this:
$$f(x) = \underbrace{(x)(x)...(x)(x)}_{u\text{ terms}}$$
Using the product rule again, we can say
$$f(x) = \underbrace{\underbrace{(1)(x)...(x)(x)}_{u \text{ terms}} + (x)(1)...(x)(x) + ... + (x)(x)...(1)(x) + (x)(x)...(x)(1)}_{u\text{ terms}}$$
which simplifies to
$$f(x)=ux^{u-1}$$

Answer (score 9):

For positive integers $n$, we can use the Binomial Theorem. Let $f(x)=x^n$. We want to find the slope of the tangent line to $y=f(x)$ at $x=a$. So take a very small $h$, and calculate 
$$\frac{(a+h)^n-a^n}{h}.$$
By the Binomial Theorem, $(a+h)^n=a^n+na^{n-1}h +\binom{n}{2}a^{n-2}h^2+\cdots$.

Since $h$ is tiny, $h^2$, $h^3$, and so on are negligible compared to $h$. Thus
$$\frac{(a+h)^n-a^n}{h}\approx na^{n-1}.$$

Comment: Ok, this explanation is way too mathy

Comment: True, it is rather symbol-laden.

Comment: I think it works.  However, you should have used the limit as $x$ approaches $0$.  @Pacerier have you dealt with binomial theorem?  It is rather a beautiful thing.  The trick to understanding this explanation lies in ignoring the $3rd,4th,5th,...$ term because when you set $h=0$, they all cancel.  The $1st$ term is canceled by the $-f(x)$ in the derivative calculation and the second term's $h$ is removed by the $h$ in the denominator of the derivative quotient.  Thus giving $na^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

This may be too advanced for you right now,
but knowing about the derivative of the log function
can be very helpful.

The basic idea is that
$(\ln(x))' = 1/x$,
where $\ln$ is the natural log.

Applying the chain rule,
$(\ln(f(x))' = f'(x)/f(x)$.

For this case,
set $f(x) = x^n$.
Then $\ln(f(x)) = \ln(x^n) = n \ln(x)$.
Taking derivatives on both sides,
$(\ln(x^n))' = f'(x)/f(x) = f'(x)/x^n$
and $(\ln(x^n))' = (n \ln(x))' = n/x$,
so
$f'(x)/x^n = n/x$
or $f'(x) = n x^{n-1}$.

More generally,
if $f(x) = \prod a_i(x)/\prod b_i(x)$,
then
$\ln(f(x)) = \sum \ln(a_i(x))-\sum \ln(b_i(x))$
so

$\begin{align}
f'(x)/f(x) &= (\ln(f(x))'\\
 &= \sum (\ln(a_i(x))'-\sum (\ln(b_i(x))'\\
&=\sum (a_i(x))'/a_i(x)-\sum (b_i(x))'/b_i(x)\\
\end{align}
$,

so
$f'(x) = f(x)\left(\sum (a_i(x))'/a_i(x)-\sum (b_i(x))'/b_i(x)\right)
$.

Note that this technique,
called logarithmic differentiation,
 generalizes both the
product and quotient rules for derivatives.