# How do I prove this $\frac{dx^n}{dx}=nx^{n-1}$ is true for every $n\geq 1$ to convince my students?

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, proof-verification

let  $p_n(x)=x^n$ be a polynomial of degree $n$. I need help to be able to explain to my students why the derivative of $p$ is defined as follows:

$$
p_n'(x)=\frac{dx^n}{dx}=nx^{n-1}
$$

for every $n\geq1$.

**Note:**  I'd prefer geometric proofs if any exist.

**Edit**:I edited the question as it is related to the recent question

Thank you for any help

Comment: Are your students ok with the Binomial Theorem?

Comment: What do you mean by "defined?" This follows from the definition of the derivative and is derived in any introductory calculus textbook.

Comment: First principles convinced me at A-level

Comment: Induction is the simplest way.

Comment: As per David Quinn's comment, here is a link using binomial theorem: http://www.mathshelper.co.uk/Differentiation%20FFP.pdf

Comment: **If** you already have the Product Rule, use it to find the derivative of $x^2=x\cdot x$, and then of $x^3=x\cdot x^2$, and then of $x^4=x\cdot x^3$ and then of $x^5=x\cdot x^4$, and the pattern will become clear.

Comment: There is a nice intuitive explanation [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/333238/28479).

Comment: @AndréNicolas That is the proof that is also given by Hairer/Wanner: *Analysis by It's History*. I guess that it's the less bureaucratic way to do it, since it rely only in the proof of the product rule, which is quite simple.

Comment: As far as *convincing* goes, it is better not to do a formal induction. If one does it in a lecture for $2,3,4,5$, in the "same" way each time, the fact that one can continue is clear to (most of) them. But it is best to do it in several ways, and when one meets the exponential function, to derive the familiar derivative of $x^n$ from that, again.  I am not so sure about the simplicity of derivation of the Product Rule, one usually uses an unmotivated trick.

Comment: There is some overkill in the conventional argument that starts with $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h)^n-x^n}{h}$.  See my second answer below. (I've posted two answers that are very different from each other.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188028/what-is-meant-by-find-the-slope-of-the-tangent-to-the-graph-of-f-at-a-general-p/1188102#1188102

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at a cube in $n$-dimensional space, whose side has changing length $x$.  Fix the sides meeting at one vertex in their places, so that all motion is motion of $n$ the sides opposite those.  Each side has $(n-1)$-dimensional volume $x^{n-1}$.  So the total size of the moving boundaries is $nx^{n-1}$.

The size of the boundary times the rate at which the boundary moves is the rate of change of size of the cube.

Therefore $x^n$ changes $nx^{n-1}$ times as fast as $x$ changes.

Comment: +1 from me, while this isn't the way I'd recommend anyone learned how to differentiate (because what would a general f(x) represent?) - it's a really good way at doing it with $x^n$!

Answer (score 7):

Differentiation from first principles is great. Draw a curve on the board, then draw the tangent to a point - that's your gradient, you can see that.

Then take $f(x+\delta x)$ and draw that, and the line connecting it to $f(x)$ for some values of $\delta x$ - this 'convinced me' (when I was 15/16) of how differentiation works, because I liked gradient of a line.

It becomes clear that "as $\delta x\rightarrow 0$ we get a better approximation"

---

We cannot divide by zero, so we cannot just plug in $\delta x =0$ this is where maths got interesting for me. What we did is we put $x^n$ as $f(x)$ (we actually used $x^2$ first, and $x^3$ but it was an AS level class) and this showed you can actually side-step the division by zero by using algebra.

Needless to say this amazed me!

---

For your $x^n$ it requires the binomial theorem. (I do recommend doing $x^2$ and $x^3$ "manually" first)

We note:

$$\frac{f(x+\delta x)-f(x)}{\delta x}=\frac{(x+\delta x)^n-x^n}{\delta x}$$
We expand:
$$=\frac{x^n+nx^{n-1}\delta x+\ldots+nx(\delta x)^{n-1}+(\delta x)^n-x^n}{\delta x}$$
We note the terms cancel to give:
$$=\frac{nx^{n-1}\delta x+\ldots+nx(\delta x)^{n-1}+(\delta x)^n}{\delta x}$$
Now we sidestep the division by zero (By factoring out a $\delta x$)
$$=\frac{\delta x(nx^{n-1} x+\ldots+nx(\delta x)^{n-2}+(\delta x)^{n-1})}{\delta x}$$
We can do the divide
$$=nx^{n-1} x+\ldots+nx(\delta x)^{n-2}+(\delta x)^{n-1}$$
NOW we can substitute $\delta x=0$ - we see:
$$=nx^{n-1}$$

My mind was blown.

Comment: You have a typo.

Comment: @mistermarko just to justify that a bit (you are of course entirely right) - when I learned this there was no "doing stuff formally" if someone asked me "why does $\frac{1}{n}\rightarrow 0$ I'd reply "because I wouldn't want to live in a world where this isn't true" - so while non-rigorous, it was perfectly suited for teaching AS students. I then came to university and was hit with the shovel that was "real analysis" and envied the physicists. That's a rant for another time.

Comment: we don't ever put dx=0.In the last step of Alec Teal's answer we just let dx converge to 0.

Comment: That's the definition of a limit.... @user254665 Remember, 15/16 year olds, limit to them is just "fancy substitution"

Answer (score 6):

Use the definition of the derivative:
$$\frac{dx^n}{dx}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)^n-x^n}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{x^n+nx^{n-1}h+\cdots+h^n-x^n}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}(nx^{n-1}+h(\cdots))=nx^{n-1}.$$

Comment: Missing some brackets on that last limit (fixed :) )

Comment: Just quickly guys, remember the question was explaining to some students (presumably, A-level (15-16 year olds)), not how to prove it in the shortest way. I could just be bitter about typing time though.

Comment: @AlecTeal, i have to upvote to your answer since it is long

Comment: @zeraouliarafik .... thanks? - I hope you read it though! Not just thought "+1 for effort"

Comment: hop your vote to the question

Answer (score 2):

When $n$ is a natural number, you can do it with the binomial theorem, as Alec Teal and David Quinn suggested.

When $n$ is a nonzero integer, you can use the previous result and the quotient rule (or some analogue of the quotient rule).

When $n$ is a nonzero rational number, you can do it with implicit differentiation: $y=x^{m/n}$ is the same as $y^n=x^m$, now differentiate implicitly using the previous result and solve for $y'$.

When $n$ is an irrational number, the details get rather messy, and it becomes easier to deal with everything rigorously by taking a detour into the exponential and logarithm functions, and defining $x^n=\exp(n \ln(x))$.

All of this assumes $x$ is positive.

Answer (score 1):

It is the coefficient of $h$ in the *linear part* of $(x+h)^n$, as a function of $h$. Now by the binomial formula:
$$(x+h)^n=x^n+nx^{n-1}h +\text{terms of higher degree in }h.$$
Thus the derivative is $\;nx^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

A zillion calculus textbooks do this by finding $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h)^n-x^n}{h}$ and expanding the binomial.

I think there's a bit of overkill in that argument: we only need the first two binomial coefficients, $1 \text{ and } n$, not all of them.

So do it like this instead:
\begin{align}
\lim_{y\to x}\frac{y^n-x^n}{y-x} & = \lim_{y\to x}  \frac{(y-x)(y^{n-1} + y^{n-2}x+y^{n-3}x^2 + \cdots + x^{n-1})}{y-x} \\[10pt]
& = \lim_{y\to x} \Big( y^{n-1} + y^{n-2}x+y^{n-3}x^2 + \cdots + x^{n-1} \Big) \\[10pt]
& = x^{n-1} + x^{n-1} + x^{n-1} + \cdots + x^{n-1}.
\end{align}